# Custom errors not working in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I've included the line `customErrors mode="On"` in my web.config file for my Sharepoint site, but I am still not getting any error messages. It just keeps telling me to include it when it errors out.

I am unsure at this point what else to do, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: from what i understand, you're trying to display the error messages. For this, go to your web.config file and change the parameters: callStack = true, and customErrors = Off

Comment: @RyanJ  Can you tell me what specific page you're failing on? Is it one of SharePoint regular pages or custom page that you've created and dropped custom web parts?  We'll need to figure out which web.config applies to your situation.

Comment: No worries Roman, I got the problem fixed :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution for this I found is using a tool called ULS Viewer, it can directly access the Sharepoint log files and will show you the exception.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

It can be downloaded from the link above!

Answer (score 2):

The SharePoint application is consists of a number of  virtual directories mapped together. You can change root web.config under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ but that can be and does get overwritten by a number of mapped virtual folders, i.e. _controltemplates, _layouts, _vti_bin, _wpresources.
If you are failing on a system pages, you may need to go and modify the web.config files in the mapped folders instead.
As you mentioned ULS usually contains all the errors, and SharePoint ULS Logviewer is indispensable tool here, http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/.